# What is difference between EDI and FHIR?

Tags: edi, hl7-fhir

i know that EDI is used for transference of electronic documents. And FHIR are standards developed by HL7 which is also used for transfer of health related documents. But can we use EDI to connect with FHIR, or are the both separate domains.
The reason i am asking for that is because i have experience in EDI and am now trying to work with IBM Watson API. The confusion is FHIR as there is requirement of following these standards for communication.
**So main thing i want to know is that can we use EDI to communicate with FHIR as in documents i have defined the protocols required for FHIR.**

Answer (score 3):

EDI means sending data electronicly as discrete, computable data elements.  You can do EDI all sorts of different ways using proprietary mechanisms or standard mechanisms.  FHIR is *a* standard for doing EDI for healthcare information.  Whether you can use FHIR data directly with Watson or not or whether you'll have to translate, I don't know.  (And what data formats Watson supports may well evolve over time.)

Comment: Are u sure that FHIR is standard for EDI, Last time i checked EDI had its own protocols for health documents change that are not related to FHIR (they are HIPAA)

Comment: EDI is an acronym for Electronic Data Interchange.  It is a generic system capability like storage or a GUI.  It doesn't imply any standard or approach - it just means data is being passed between two systems.  There are numerous standards that can be used for doing EDI in the healthcare space.  HIPAA does mandate the use of certain standards and enforces rules around some types of healthcare EDI in the U.S.  However, there are lots types of exchange where HIPAA allows a variety of standards, including FHIR.  And there's lots of healthcare exchanges not covered by hIPAA at all.

Answer (score 0):

To know about FHIR, information on HL-7 is must. Basically HL-7 is organisation that develops standards related to health care and in HL-7 a developer team decided that due to sudden rise in EHR (Electronic Health Records), there should be a way that developer can implement the standards developed by HL-7. So they created FHIR, which means FHIR is health standard for developers. EDI is basic transfer of data/information/documents and if they are health related and in regard to development of EHR system then it is FHIR. 
 For more Information check this Blog [Is FHIR an Industry Disrupter?](https://blog.heliossoftware.com/is-fhir-an-industry-disrupter-f55333058602) from Steve Munini (All credit to him and HELIOS for this awesome read which made me understand this concept clearly)

Answer (score 0):

EDI-Is a blanket cross-domain definition on Electronic Data Exchange. Now on healthcare space you have the EDI/X12 for claims billing and HL7 for medical information exchange HL7=XML standard/heavy payload and FHIR HL7-JSON standards whereby the latter is a lightweight flexible messaging standard.

Comment: By HL7, I think you mean HL7 v2.  (HL7 is an organization, not a standard.  HL7 defines many standards).  HL7 v2 *can* be sent using XML, but most implementations use a character-delimited syntax.  FHIR can be sent using JSON, XML or RDF.  FHIR also supports multiple exchange architectures including REST and documents as well as messaging.  (REST is most common.)